# Is there any way to import JSON zip file into mongodb using mongoimport?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell, mongoimport

I have created a zip file from a large JSON file(containing json array). I want to use this zip file in mongoimport command. Is it possible to import this zip file in mongodb using mongoimport command?

**COMMAND:**

`mongoimport --db test --collection inventory ^ --authenticationDatabase admin --username <user> --password <password> ^ --drop --file ~\downloads\inventory.crud.json.zip --jsonArray`

**OUTPUT:**

> Failed: error reading separator after document #1: bad JSON array
> format

Since this is a zip file it does not find a valid json array. Is there a way to unzip file in mongoimport command?

Comment: try removing --jsonArray option from your mongoimport cmd

Comment: Data is a valid JSON . I already did test with same data file without compression and it worked.

Comment: @ManishChaudhary I tried removing jsonArray, but that is not the issue. import expects a json array but it gets a zip file.